# Can't connect to Windows ServiceBus via HTTPS

Tags: c#, .net, windows, azure, servicebus

I'm trying to connect to a windows service bus using HTTPS. Here is my app config setting:

```
  <appSettings>
  <add key="Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString" value="Endpoint=https://example-service.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=example-shared-secret-value"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Here is the code that is trying to create the connection:

```
return SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, RequestTopicName,
                                                                 SubscriptionName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
```

However, it's not working, throwing this error:

> Unable to create MessagingFactory using connection string. The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'sb'. See inner exception for details. Check your connection string and then try again. For more information please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=249089

And the inner exception:

*The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'sb'. at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessagingFactory..ctor(IEnumerable`1 baseAddresses, NetMessagingTransportSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.NetMessagingTransportSettings.Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ITransportSettings.BeginCreateFactory(IEnumerable`1 physicalUriAddresses, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactorySettings.OnBeginCreateFactory(IEnumerable`1 uriAddresses, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactorySettings.BeginCreateFactory(IEnumerable`1 uriAddresses, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.CreateMessagingFactoryAsyncResult..ctor(MessagingFactorySettings settings, IEnumerable`1 addresses, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.BeginCreate(IEnumerable`1 addresses, MessagingFactorySettings factorySettings, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.BeginCreate(IEnumerable`1 addresses, MessagingFactorySettings factorySettings, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.BeginCreate(IEnumerable`1 addresses, TokenProvider tokenProvider, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingFactory.Create(IEnumerable`1 addresses, TokenProvider tokenProvider)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationManager.CreateFactory(IEnumerable`1 endpoints, IEnumerable`1 stsEndpoints, String operationTimeout, String issuerName, String issuerKey, String domain, String user, SecureString password)*

If I change the connection string to use **sb**.example-service.servicebus.windows.net instead of **https**.example-service.servicebus.windows.net it will work, but I really need to use HTTPS instead of SB.

Any ideas why the client is expecting 'sb'? How can I configure the client to use 'https'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: change the "https" part of the connection string back to "sb", that has to be "sb". Now add this line of code:

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;
```